# 'node keystone' gives 'libsass' bindings not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I juist installed keystone in a separate folder, when I try to run it with 'Node kystone' I receive this error:

> { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code:
>   'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
>
> js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
>   D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_backend\node_modules\keysto
>   ne\lib\core\mount.js:316
>                                   throw e;
>                                   ^
>
> Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
>       at getBinding (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_backend\
>   node_modules\node-sass-middleware\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22:11)
>       at Object. (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_
>   backend\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:18
>   8:23)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_
>   backend\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\middleware.js:1:74)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at mount (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_backend\node_
>   modules\keystone\lib\core\mount.js:306:21)
>       at start (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_backend\node_
>   modules\keystone\lib\core\start.js:239:7)
>       at Object. (D:\Documenten\Projecten3_Groep6\backend\groep6_
>   backend\keystone.js:57:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

I already reinstalled node-sass but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before and I downgraded my NodeJs.

You can find how to do this here:
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/

Remember that you need to install Keystone again after switching to another version of NodeJS